# Avoid *{padding=0;margin:0 } css in content page?

Tags: css, asp.net-4.0

I have written in css file so that there is no gap at top. It works fine.

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

but i don't this to applied to particular page as i am getting the formatted text from a richtextbox control which is saved in database.

How to handle this? Is it valid to give 0.5 px in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to have that at the very top of your css page.

CSS actually stands for Cascading Style Sheet and this is where that is really obvious.

If you put `*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}` at the top of your file, any rules that are defined later in your file will overwrite this rule. The ***lower*** the rule in the 'cascade' the ***later*** it gets applied to the document.

See [the cascade spec for how order in css is applied](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order).

Answer (score 2):

You can override that in any additional page with the !important property or overloading the initial definition after the first css file is loaded.

I think you're asking about how to allow a gap at the top of an element? You don't specify what the gap is ontop of.

You can use margin 1px or try em values: 0.5em as a measurement.

Usually, I use css like this:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; } 
#wrapper * { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

That way everything within the wrapper will have margin 0 and padding 0 but other elements on the page will not unless they are inside the wrapper object.

The other option is to declare your CSS in a way that it will be overridden:

For this answer your code could be something like this based on the other comments:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } 
#wrapper * { margin:15px; padding:0; }
```

Then anything in the wrapper ID will have different settings.

Comment: when we don't specify *{margin:0px;padding:0px} then there is gap between div and top of page. To avoid that gap i have put that.